# How can I import a testclass properly to inherit from, without it being run as a test

Tags: python, inheritance, pytest, python-unittest, nose

## Context

I have a test class where all my tests inherit from. It cant run by itself as it really doesnt contain any setup info

I wanted to add a test which is executed by ALL tests (adding it to the baseclass seems logical)

But now I notice the basetestclass( => Foo) which I import is being detected as a test itself and runs and is visible in the reports

## Code

the base class in base.py

```
from unittest import TestCase

class Foo(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # prepare the generic setup stuff based on what is defined in the child class
        print("setupclass Foo done")

    def test_run_in_all_inherited_tests(self):
        print("fooBar")
        assert True
```

the real test in test_something.py

```
from base import Foo # <= This is being detected as a testclass object and thus will be executed

class TestFoo(Foo):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # define specific test setup
        super().setUpClass()
        print("setup TestFoo done")

    def test_pass(self):
        pass

    def test_assert(self):
        assert False
```

This triggers a testrun of the imported Foo

[image: pycharm testrun]

## The Question

How can I import Foo without that its being detected as a 'test'
If I remove the test to run in all tests all is fine.

Adding `@nottest` decorator to Foo wont work since then also all inherited classes are defined nottest.

It needs to run on `nose`, `pytest` and `unittest` testrunners

I noticed if I changed the import statement like below that it also works. But that would mean adjusting a few hundreds of testfiles in different repos. (I'd like to avoid that)

```
import base
class TestFoo(base.Foo):
```

Comment: `Foo.setUp` should probably be responsible for making sure that `Foo.test_run_in_all_inherited_tests` is runnable. Each subclass can inherit (and override as necessary) this method.

Comment: of course in this little example that's entirely true :-) since `test_run_in_all_inherited_tests` in this example doesnt do anything. BUT then each test run I would execute `Foo.test_run_in_all_inherited_tests` for a "generic" scenario + a second time as `TestFoo.test_run_in_all_inherited_tests` for the specific setup => the testresults would not be factual as I dont want to run or see the result of `Foo.test_run_in_all_inherited_tests`

Comment: @chepner I think I'm on to something. if an object has the `__test__` attr as `True` then it will be a test => or not if `__test__` is `False`. Now only have the `Foo.__test__` return `False` and the `TestFoo.__test__` return `True` without adjusting the `TestFoo` (as said way too many file changes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to the answer seems to be that each test has an attribute `__test__` which is set to `True` when it is a test.

Setting it to `False` when the class should not be a test will then let the test collector ignore this class.

The answer assumes I can only do changes in the base.py

In python 3.9 classmethod and property decorators can be combined so I wrote a separate answer for that

## answer for < py3.9

the base class in base.py

```
from unittest import TestCase

class MetaFoo(type):
    @property
    def __test__(cls):
        return cls != Foo

class Foo(TestCase, metaclass=MetaFoo):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # prepare the generic setup stuff based on what is defined in the child class
        print("setupclass Foo done")

    def test_run_in_all_inherited_tests(self):
        print("fooBar")
        assert True
```

## answer for >= py3.9

the base class in base.py

```
from unittest import TestCase

class Foo(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    @property
    def __test__(cls):
        return cls != Foo

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # prepare the generic setup stuff based on what is defined in the child class
        print("setupclass Foo done")

    def test_run_in_all_inherited_tests(self):
        print("fooBar")
        assert True
```

## the actual test

test_something.py

```
from base import Foo # <= This will not be detected as a test anymore as __test__ returns False

class TestFoo(Foo):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # define specific test setup
        super().setUpClass()
        print("setup TestFoo done")

    def test_pass(self):
        pass

    def test_assert(self):
        assert False
```

This doesnt trigger a testrun of the imported Foo anymore
[image: pycharm test run]